# Export database from SQL Server 2008 R2 Instance to SQL Express 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-r2

I ran into a issue about Import/Export on SQL Server.

I have a database on SQL Server 2008 R2 instance running on my laptop.

I want to attach it on a SQL Server Express 2008 instance running on Windows 2003 server.

Due there is no management studio on my server Is it possible to export database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Express 2008 instance ?
Depend on [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5923/attach-sql-server-2008-r2-on-sql-server-express-2008/5947#5947) answer I think its possible.
But when I want to use Import Export tool on destination setting I should choose destination configuration.
How can I get around this?

I want to know Is it possible to move R2 schema data to SQL Server 2008 express using Import / Export tool ?
If yes I think it generate script for us and I don't have management studio on server. Is it possible to execute generated script on a management studio running on my system and then move MDF file to server ?

P S : Should I ask this question on [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already asked this question on dba.stackexchange.com:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5923/attach-sql-server-2008-r2-on-sql-server-express-2008/

The answer hasn't changed. You can't attach/restore a 2008 R2 database to a 2008 instance. You either need to upgrade the 2008 instance to 2008 R2, or you need to move the schema and data in another way.  For example, the [import/export wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) should help with this (if it's not working, you need to explain what that means), as will 3rd party tools - [see some options here](http://www.onetooneglobal.com/otocorporate-posts/2009/06/01/the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/).

Comment: Thank you. current question is about Import/Export tool and previous was about Compatibility level.
I just want to know Is it possible to move R2 schema data to SQL Server 2008 express ?
If yes I think it generate script for us and I don't have management studio on server. Is it possible to execute generated script on a management studio running on my system and then move MDF file to server ?

Comment: If you have Management Studio on your workstation, then you can create a registered server to the 2008 instance. You can generate the scripts from the local instance and run them on the 2008 instance, or you can use the local instance as the source and the remote server as the destination using the wizard. There is no MDF file to move - the whole problem here is that you CAN'T just move the MDF file from your local system because it is a newer version and is not compatible.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron :]
Generate script from database tool made my work.

Answer (score 1):

> P S : Should I ask this question on DBA ?

Yes.

But, to answer your question, you can't restore from 2008R2 to 2008. I know the naming convention used is, at best, completely confusing, the reality is that they are 2 separate versions just like 2005 and 2008, and are unable to restore to previous versions.